# Problema in tikzmath with two outputs

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikzmath, function

I haver a MWE where I want to calculate a sum and the associated error, implemented in the funcion serieF.
How can I implement in the function to return two outputs, i.e., the variables \s and \e and call these variables next?

Observation: I need to use tikzmath.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fpu}
\usepackage{pgf}

\tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
  \tikzmath{
  function serieF(\n) {
      real \s; real \a; real \e;
      \s = 0;
      \e = 0;
       for \i in {1,...,\n}{
         if isodd(\i+1) == 1 then {
         \s = \s - 1/(2*\i-1); % 
         };
         if isodd(\i+1) == 0 then {
         \s = \s + 1/(2*\i-1); % 
         };
         \e = abs(1/(2*\i-1));
       };
      return \s;
    };
    real \s \e;
    \s = serieF(100);
  }%


\begin{document}

The approximation for the serie is \s~ with an error of 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You really don't want to load the package `fp` twice.

Comment: Correct, I have eliminated. But, and the solution?

Comment: I'm not skilled enough with `tikz` to help with the solution.  But there are many others here with that knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a better way of making global the internal variables of a function, but this hack works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fpu}
\usepackage{pgf}

\tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
\tikzmath{
    function serieF(\n) {
        real \s; real \a; real \e;
        \s = 0;
        \e = 0;
        for \i in {1,...,\n}{
            if isodd(\i+1) == 1 then {
                \s = \s - 1/(2*\i-1); %
            };
            if isodd(\i+1) == 0 then {
                \s = \s + 1/(2*\i-1); %
            };
            \e = abs(1/(2*\i-1));
        };
        print {\xdef\mysum{\s}\xdef\myerr{\e}};%
    };
}%

\begin{document}

  \tikzmath{serieF(100);}
  The approximation for the serie
  is~\mysum{} with an error of~\myerr.

\end{document}
```

[image]